# Upper subplot won't show x tick labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting data from dataframe in 3 subplots. I want the x labels to show on each of the plots. However, with my code only the lower two plots show the x labels and I don't understand why.

The code is:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(11, 10))

ticks_to_use = df3.index[::5]
labels = [ i.strftime("%m/%d") for i in ticks_to_use ]

df3['Temp [Degrees_C]'].plot(ax=axes[0])
ax2 = axes[0].twinx()

color = 'tab:red'
ax2.set_ylabel(r'$\sigma_{\theta}$', color=color)  
df3['Cond [mS/cm]'].plot(ax=ax2, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

for i in range(3):
    axes[i].set_xticks(ticks_to_use)
    axes[i].set_xticklabels(labels)

axes[0].set_xlabel('time')
axes[0].set_ylabel('s1 and s2')
axes[0].grid(True)

df3['Salin [PSU]'].plot(ax=axes[1])
df3['Pres [deciBars]'].plot(ax=axes[2])

fig.tight_layout(pad=3.0)
```

And the result:

[image]

What is wrong? I guess it's something with the `twinx` but I'm not sure.

EDIT:

df3 looks like this:

```
    Temp [Degrees_C]    Cond [mS/cm]    Salin [PSU] Pres [deciBars]
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sss             
2020-01-27 22:00:59 14.470891   19.066957   14.510464   12.198908
2020-01-28 03:00:59 14.553947   19.301285   14.673590   12.481595
2020-01-28 08:00:59 14.501740   19.310037   14.700473   12.593718
2020-01-28 13:00:59 14.425415   18.531609   14.083557   12.626744
2020-01-28 18:00:59 14.414717   16.155998   12.134919   12.469164
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you please add a sample of df3?

Comment: I've edited my question and added how `df3` looks like

Answer (score 0):

```
Data
df3=pd.DataFrame({'time':['2020-01-27 22:00:59','2020-01-28 03:00:59','2020-01-28 08:00:59','2020-01-28 13:00:59','2020-01-28 18:00:59'], 'Temp [Degrees_C]':[14.470891,14.553947,14.501740,14.425415,14.414717],'Cond [mS/cm]':[19.066957,19.301285,19.310037,18.531609,16.155998],'Salin [PSU]':[14.510464,14.673590,14.700473,14.083557,12.134919],'Pres [deciBars]':[12.198908,12.481595,12.593718,12.626744,12.469164]})
df3
```

Please Try

```
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(11, 10))
    ticks_to_use = df3.index[::5]
    labels = [ i.strftime("%m/%d") for i in ticks_to_use ]
    df3['Temp [Degrees_C]'].plot(ax=axes[0])
    ax2 = axes[2].twinx()
    color = 'tab:red'
    ax2.set_ylabel(r'$\sigma_{\theta}$', color=color)  
    df3['Cond [mS/cm]'].plot(ax=ax2, color=color)
    ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
    for i in range(3):
        axes[i].set_xticks(ticks_to_use)
        axes[i].set_xticklabels(labels)
    axes[0].set_xlabel('time')
    axes[0].set_ylabel('s1 and s2')
    axes[0].grid(True)

    df3['Salin [PSU]'].plot(ax=axes[1])
    df3['Pres [deciBars]'].plot(ax=axes[2])

    fig.tight_layout(pad=3.0)
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I try that, the lower plot is with the two lines instead of the upper one. I need the two-line plot to be in the upper one